# Why does accessing local variables during anonymous class construction cause NPE

Tags: groovy, anonymous-class

Given a relatively simple class

```
class TestNull {

    static void main(String [] a) {

        Long whatever = 1

        // this works
        new Runnable() {
            void run() { println(whatever) }
        }.run()

        // this doesn't
        new Weird() {
            @Override
            void x() { println(whatever) } // NPE
        }
    }

    static abstract class Weird {
        Weird() { x() }
        abstract void x();
    }

}
```

executing `main()` throws an NPE trying to access `whatever` during the construction of anonymous class extending `Weird`. The same code works fine in Java, and it also works fine as long as the variable is accessed **after** the class is constructed (hence the example with anonymous `Runnable`).

I wonder what's going on here, whether this is a Groovy bug (I'm testing with 3.0.5), or it's supposed to be like that. But then I'm not sure what exactly is `null` in this case, and how do you even logically explain what the rule is for accessing external scope variables from anonymous classes...

NPE:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.example.TestNull$2.x(TestNull.groovy:15)
    at org.example.TestNull$Weird.<init>(TestNull.groovy:20)
    at org.example.TestNull$2.<init>(TestNull.groovy)
    at org.example.TestNull.main(TestNull.groovy:13)
```

Comment: Works without problem and prints the number twice. That's groovy 3.0.8. What are your versions?

Comment: @ernest_k Then it is a Groovy bug. I was running on 3.0.5. It does work with 3.0.8

Comment: Maybe try upgrading to latest version and see if that fixes it. Or do you mean that you tested on 3.0.8 and it worked?

Comment: @ernest_k Yes, running on 3.0.8 works.